# Rails 5 (AWS Amazon) S3_BUCKET_NAME Key not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I'm aware that lots of people already encountered to this problem, but either their solution does not work for me or we're not at the same stage of production. I did lot of googling, but nothing helped.

This is my .env class:

```
S3_BUCKET_NAME=
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCES_KEY=
AWS_REGION
```

When I pass in the values I'm supposed to pass in and go to `rails c` and type `ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME')` i get this error

[image]

I've also tried to add `require "dotenv-rails"` in my `application.rb`, but in that case I can not even start the console.

If anyone has any idea, it would help a lot : )

This is what happens when I run the console

[image]

Comment: Is this happening in the development environment or production?

Comment: What happens when you `require "dotenv-rails"` that you can't start the console?

Comment: @infused It happens in the development env

Comment: @Dave I added a picture of an error

Answer (score 1):

"key not found" means that the S3_BUCKET_NAME does not have a value, so if you are using ENV variables, you need to set them in the enviroment, for example i have this file in production:

```
if Rails.env.production?
    CarrierWave.configure do |config|
        config.fog_credentials = {
            :provider => 'AWS',
            :aws_access_key_id => ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY'],
            :aws_secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET_KEY']
        }
        config.fog_directory = ENV['S3_BUCKET']
    end
end
```

in that way you can set your variables via terminal wihout any error, e.g. heroku config:set S3_BUCKET=name_of_my_bucket

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answer.

I managed to solved it earlier, I guess the problem is that this new version of gem `dotenv` has a slightly different way of applying it.

Or at least it was only in my case. I was not able to require `"dotenv-rails"` in `application.rb` file, but when I put in the `GEMFILE` along with the gem itself, it all compiled nicely.

This line solved it:

```
 gem 'dotenv-rails', require: 'dotenv/rails-now'
```